# Does rspec install require 4 gems installed?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

According to this tutorial: http://rspec.codeschool.com/levels/1 (2 minute mark) when you type in "gem install rspec" to install Rspec it should download 4 gems. However my command line, Windows, installed only 1 gem.

```
Successfully installed rspec-3.0.0
1 gem installed
```

Am I missing the other parts of Rspec, and, if so, how can I manually add them?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already had all the gems installed.  The first time I install rspec I get 6 gems installed:

```
> gem install rspec

Fetching: rspec-support-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-support-3.0.4
Fetching: rspec-core-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-core-3.0.4
Fetching: diff-lcs-1.2.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed diff-lcs-1.2.5
Fetching: rspec-expectations-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-expectations-3.0.4
Fetching: rspec-mocks-3.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-mocks-3.0.4
Fetching: rspec-3.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rspec-3.0.0
6 gems installed
```

But once all the gems are installed, installing rspec again just shows 1 gem installed:

```
> gem install rspec

Successfully installed rspec-3.0.0
1 gem installed
```

To verify what gems are installed, run:

```
gem list
```